# Socket in thread zero file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets

C++. Ubuntu server 14.04. g++ 4.9

I read MANY info about that but... my problem is something another that standart issues with it. So.... 
few words about architecture of my app

- main process with some management functions
- 30 subthreads that do some work via socket connections

I wrote the app for windows first. And in windows it works good. But I need it to be rewritten on linux. All is ok I rewrote it but... it crashes. When I debugged it I found an issue I dont understand and no answer in internet - so
in every of these 30 subthreads when I put code

```
sock=socket(....); ///all is ok with this string
```

it returns ZERO. In EVERY thread. And therefor all of these threads use ONE socket and it means app is crazy))
I tried to put for example this code

```
int fd=open("tmp.tmp",....); ///I forget what flag is there
```

and it returns ZERO too.
then I tried to do the same in main processs - and it returns normal integers like 15,16 and so on.

Then I tried to do something like

```
while (sock<=0)
{
    sock=socket(...);
    usleep(91000);
    if (sock<=0)
    {
        try{
            close(sock);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            //blablabla
        }
    }
}
```

and.... it GIVE me sometimes integers - but it happens once in 2-3 minutes. So extremally rarely. That means it is some SYSTEM trouble. System dont want to give me real File Descriptor of opened socket...
also I used mutex to not create sockets at the same time by many threads.

I know that threads in linux uses the same file descriptor table. But why it returns ZERO in all cases? Why it DOESNT return zero in main process? And HOW to resolve it?(

Thanks....

UPDATE!
That is a sample code the  same I use

```
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"
#include "fcntl.h"

void stthread(int n)
{
    int x,tfd;

    for (x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        tfd=open("tmp.tmp",O_WRONLY);
        printf("PROCESS %i: TFD = %i\r\n",n,tfd);
        close(tfd);
        sleep(3);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    for (x=0;x<30;x++)
    {
        std::thread tq(stthread, x);
        tq.detach();
    }       
    sleep(100);
    return 0;
}
```

But this one works normal. If it would work like my main code its result could be like

```
PROCESS 1: TFD = 0
PROCESS 2: TFD = 0
```

and so on

Comment: Seeing an [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great.

Comment: You do not want to close the FD if equal `0`as per the snippet you show. `0` is Standard Input (`stdin`)! Also closing an FD with a value `<1` does not make sense, as it's not a valid FD.

Comment: @alk: `0` usually is stdin. Looks like OP is closing all the descriptors after fork (not sure if OP actually mentions threads and processes randomly?) so everytime, first new socket in subprocess get `0` fd. @Roman: `0` is perfectly correct file descriptor in unix. `-1` is failure and this is that you should check in unix code.

Comment: Ok, so are you doing multiprocessing or multithreading?

Comment: alk - I close it for not to think about it that time. Problem isnt in it. Problem is that it is ZERO - and stdin - is open. In main thread it doesnt return me zero. also it sometime return me 15 and 16 as mentioned in these 30 threads but very rare

Comment: Zbigniew Zagórski - I understand that. As I said - isnt problem that it is zero - problem is that in ALL threads it returns zero - as I read anywhere that is some problem with linux kernel. It returns zero in case it cant return right value. But Im not sure.

Comment: Ok let me write a simple full code app and demonstrate what I mean

Comment: How do you create the subthreads?

Comment: Try to run your app with `strace`. Also C++ `try` `catch` has nothing to do with `close(sock);`.

Comment: JMA - I use std::thread

Comment: I updated description

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Are you sure your main thread finishes after all worker threads ? You should probably `join` threads instead of `detach`.

Comment: I am sure and in real code it must work in days and monthes. It isnt problem. I found a strange issue and test it now.

Comment: In my app I use in this function (lets say stthread) - I use creating a new object in which there are many functions with connecting to server and reconnecting to it and messaging and so on. In this object there are troubles with file descriptors. Out of it - no problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need some time to determine and describe problem better. Because as I see I can give more info but I need few more time. Thanks a lot for helping. I will write more details

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for all and sorry. Trouble was in my algorythm. It closed and opened the socket multiple times while in cycle.
Thanks a lot for all.